# Xpaths are changing dynamically

Tags: selenium, dom

Im currently auotmating an web application using a selenium framework.For locating the elements im using xpath. For particular drop downs(with a filter in it) in the application the xpaths are getting changed frequently(for the available options in the drop down).The options in the drop down are inside the span section. Is there are any way to  handle the dynamic xpath? Currently im using firebug to get the xpaths.

Comment: give some html code to understand what changing dynamically?

Comment: Initially the xpath for the option under drop down that i want to click was: "/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/ul/li[2]/label/span" But currently the xpath for the same option has changed to" /html/body/div[1]/div[7]/ul/li[2]/label/span". Is there any reason for the xpath getting changed and i wanted to know whether xpath can change dynamically.

Comment: instead writing relative xpath create an xpath with class, id or text. Firebug create a relative xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use XPATH text matching if you know what to expect.

```
  //*[text()='DropdownValue']
```

if you have list elements in the dropdown:

```
  //li[text()='DropdownValue']
```

If you could provide example of the dropdown structure or just the HTML code of your case, it would be much easier to find a suitable solution.

Comment: I wanted to select "Abereen District" option from the drop down. when i inspect that particular option with the fire bug the following structure is shown:   <label class="ui-corner-all ui-state-active bcg-ui-state-selected bcg-ui-state-hover" title="" for="ui-multiselect-viewStudentsOrgFilter_district-option-1">
<input id="ui-multiselect-viewStudentsOrgFilter_district-option-1" type="radio" title="Abereen District" value="67434" name="multiselect_viewStudentsOrgFilter_district" aria-selected="true">
<span>Abereen District</span>

Comment: I suggest using this: //span[text()='Abereen District']

Answer (score 0):

You could get every element inside your dropdown, get the index of the element which contains the text and then click it:

```
List<WebElement>elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath from every element"));
elems.get(getIndex(elems, "Abereen District")).click();



private int getIndex(List<WebElement>elems, String elemText) {

        for(int i = 0; i < elems.size(); i++)
        {
            if(elems.get(i).getText().contains(elemText))
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```